# cant access to django post request key

Tags: python, django, post, request, postman

I write a Django web application and this project have one function that gives request from client, this request has one key this key is "tokene' 
when I send this request with Postman, my function cant find 'tokene' key so I write a small python code to send Request and this code is work!
when I use Postman my response is "please send token !" and 
when I use my code the response is a Json 
why?

## its my postman urls

http://localhost:8000/submit/expensequery?tokene=123456789

```
# its my python code 
import requests
r = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/submit/expensequery/', data={'tokene':'123456789'})
print (r.url)





# its my webapplications function 
def query_expenses(request):
    if (request.POST.has_key('tokene')):
        this_token = request.POST['tokene']
        num = request.POST.get('num', 10)
        this_user = get_object_or_404(User, token__token=this_token)
        expenses = 
        expense.objects.filter(user_name=this_user).order_by('-date') 
        [:num]
        expenses_serialized = serializers.serialize("json", expenses)
        return JsonResponse(expenses_serialized, encoder=JSONEncoder, safe=False)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('please send token !')



    #its my application urls.py
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^accant/',include('accant.urls')),
        url(r'',include('web.urls')),



    ]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)



    #its my web.urls.py

    urlpatterns = [
       url(r'^submit/expense/$',views.expense_func),
       url(r'^submit/income/$',views.income_func),
       url(r'^submit/expensequery/?$',views.query_expenses),
       url(r'^/test/',views.test),
    ]
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Probably because you are using `GET` method in postman.

Comment: @Rakesh No i select post and my function is require_POST

Answer (score 0):

The `has_key` functionality is deprecated in favour of using `'key' in request.POST`. Therefore your if condition won't work. You should do `if 'tokene' in request.POST:`

Comment: I change it but my problem still yet

Comment: Can you post your urls.py?

Comment: I add this to my post

Comment: You don't need that `?` at the end of your expensequery url but I'm not sure if that's causing the issue